# Declaration of variable in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to declare `temp` variable, though I already studied syntax, and according to me, it is right, but then too, it shows error :`Undefined temp and t.`

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_reciever BEFORE INSERT
ON one_to_one FOR each row
BEGIN
select employee_id into temp from employee_master where employee_id = NEW.reciever_id;
IF temp!=0 THEN
insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
ELSE
   select count(*) into t from parent_master where parent_id=new.reciever_id;
   IF t!=0 THEN
     insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
   END IF;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a the `DECLARE` clause which is used to declare variables (as could be guessed from its name):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_reciever BEFORE INSERT
ON one_to_one FOR each row
-- Begining of the DECLARE section you're missing
DECLARE
    temp NUMBER;
    t NUMBER;
-- End of the missing section
BEGIN
    select employee_id into temp from employee_master where employee_id = NEW.reciever_id;
    IF temp!=0 THEN
        insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
    ELSE
        select count(*) into t from parent_master where parent_id=new.reciever_id;
        IF t!=0 THEN
           insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
        END IF;
   END IF;
END
```

**EDIT**: The above is an Oracle solution, as per the OP's tags. For MySQL, the `DECLARE` syntax is slightly different:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_reciever BEFORE INSERT
ON one_to_one FOR each row
BEGIN
    -- Declarations
    DECLARE temp NUMERIC;
    DECLARE t NUMERIC;
    -- End declarations
    select employee_id into temp from employee_master where employee_id = NEW.reciever_id;
    IF temp!=0 THEN
        insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
    ELSE
        select count(*) into t from parent_master where parent_id=new.reciever_id;
        IF t!=0 THEN
           insert into one_to_one values(new.message_id,new.reciever_id,new.read);
        END IF;
   END IF;
END
```

Comment: Your solution gives me following error:                         MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE
    temp NUMBER' at line 4

Comment: Your post was tagged with [tag:oracle] and [tag:plsql], not [tag:mysql], so I answered for Oracle. Let's try to whip something up...

Comment: ... here, check this out

Comment: actually it was not me who added tag of oracle and plsql,i just tagged trigger, and i am so sorry to inform you that still same error exists in my mysql

Comment: I am running in phpmyadmin, but it still shows the same error